# How to show objects from different files on the same surface with Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a very simple 2D game in `pygame` and I've made several files with classes in them that defines the characteristics of a few particles and how the terrain is going to look. The problem is that I can't get them to both show on the same surface. I've tried fiddling around with it but when I run it, the terrain ends up showing without the particles. The particles appears in a separate window only after I've exited the first window.
So my question is:

How do I show objects from different files on the same surface/screen with Pygame?

I'm using the pygame.draw function to draw the player and the particles.

Part of one of the classes:

```
class Volcano():
    def __init__(self, x, y, size):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.colour = (0, 0, 255)
        self.thickness = 1
        self.speed = 0
        self.angle = 0

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.size, self.thickness)
```

Comment: You import the objects to the file the Surface is, or the other way around, and then blit them.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman  Thank you, but I still don't fully understand. I've added some extra code in my post. When I call the pygame.draw.circle function I need to put the surface as an argument. The problem is that if I don't define the surface in the same file, it won't know what surface to draw it on. How do I fix this?

Comment: There are many ways to do it and they all depends on your code. Where is `screen` defined, is `screen` global or local, where is `Volcano` defined, where is `Volcano` initiated, do you have a module handling the drawing or do you have a "main" module. One way is to do `from main import screen` in all modules that needs `screen` provided that `screen` is global and defined in a module called `main` and that you don't have any imports from the main module.

Comment: Or pass the `screen` Surface as an argument to the `display` method provided that `Volcano` is initiated in the same module as `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

The target *Surface* needs to be an argument of the `draw` method:

```py
class Volcano():
    # [...]

    def display(self, surf):
        pygame.draw.circle(surf, self.colour, 
            (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.size, self.thickness)
```

Pass the `screen` *Surface* to the `draw` method when it is called:

```py
volcano = Volcano(x, y, size)
```

```py
volcano.draw(screen)
```